# How to determine which displays are enabled/disabled

Tags: x11, xrandr, display

I am able to enable or disable my LVDS display using

```
xrandr --output LVDS --auto
xrandr --output LVDS --off
```

respectively, but how can I programmatically determine whether the display is enabled?

`xrandr -q` shows LVDS as connected regardless of enabled/disabled state.

Comment: I don't have an LVDS display to disable on this machine to check, but I suggest `xrandr > on; xrandr --output LVDS --off; xrandr > off; diff -dbU3 on off`. Add in `--verbose` if needed. I'm pretty sure `xrandr` actually tells you.

Comment: diff on off: <<< LVDS connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm\n 1680x1050     59.88*+
>>> LVDS connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)\n>    1680x1050     59.88 +.  YEP!

Answer (score 3):

```
if xrandr --listactivemonitors | grep -q "LVDS"; then echo "enabled"; else echo "disabled"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

following the comment of @derobert:

VGA-0 off:

```
VGA-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02 
...
```

VGA-0 on:

```
VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300mm
1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02 
...
```

so, you could check the return value of this quiet `grep` to see if it is actually enabled (you can of course reduce it to a more general regex)

```
grep -q 'VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300' \
&& echo "connected AND enabled"
```

or, for your output (taken from comment above):

```
grep -q 'LVDS connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm' \
  && echo "connected AND enabled"
```

Comment: thanks, xdpyinfo only gives one screen for some reason, but see derobert's comment

Comment: @colin see update

Comment: More general: `xrandr | grep -q "$display connected [0-9]"` where `$display` is your dispay's ID (e.g. `LVDS` in OP's case)

Comment: Sometimes a specific monitor can be mentioned as primary and so you might need: `grep -E "connected (primary )?[0-9]+"`.